# Return query results in an array

Tags: c#, backbone.js, marionette, ashx

I have a stored procedure that an ashx page calls.  The ashx page then sends the result(GUIDs that correspond to records that were inserted) of the stored procedure to a marionette application.  Currently everything works fine except the only way i am able to get the results to the marionette application is using Response.Write.  That just sends back a string of all the GUIDs.  Is there a way to get the results into marionette in an array?

Comment: You could serialize the GUIDs into xml, send that xml to your application, and deserialize that into your array again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get array as json, do it like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write("{ \"yourarr\": [] }"); // your array here
```